# Is pigment grade titanium dioxide likely to contain any impurities that are toxic?

Tags: safety, toxicity

I have a bag of titanium dioxide of pigment quality, unknown source. I am curious to know if the manufacturing process of titanium dioxide makes it likely that it contains any toxic by products / impurities.

Would it for example be safe to use pigment grade titanium dioxide to manufacture sunblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDS for titanium dioxide, the substance itself is suspected of causing cancer. See, for example, [this link](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=US&language=en&productNumber=14021&brand=SIAL&PageToGoToURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fsial%2F14021%3Flang%3Den).

My opinion is that, in general, it's not a good idea to use reagents from unknown sources for any purpose, especially something like sunblock.